# How can I split String with regex

Tags: regex, split

```
`“Hakan2Ev"-> Hakan 2 Ev
"Hakan2Ev2"-> Hakan 2 Ev 2  , "Ha2Oy2Het3Magara4", "(Ha2Oy2)" ve "(Ha2Oy2)3"
"Ha2Oy2Het3Magara4" -> Ha 2 Oy 2 Het 3 Magara 4
"(Ha2Oy2)12" -> ( Ha 2 Oy 2 ) 12
```

I just want to split all words starts with uppercase, numbers and parenthesis
Im beginner about regex thank you

I tried this but it just split words starts with uppercase

```
String[] strArray = cumle.split("(?=\\p{Lu})");
```

Comment: what flavor of regex?

Comment: I think you meant Perl-like
for java

Comment: here is a one possibility:  ([A-Z0-9].*?(?=[A-Z0-9]|\Z))    https://regex101.com/r/6ip7aI/1

Comment: ([A-Z0-9()].*?(?=[A-Z0-9()]))
I turned this can u include last character and adopt for java?

Comment: How about [`\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*|\p{L}+|\d+|[^\p{L}\d+]`](https://regex101.com/r/Flje9E/1) (see [Java demo](https://tio.run/##dVFdT8IwFH12v6LhqXPa6PSN8EDmEkxADNMnQHLd6ih0XdN1CIH99lm28RGC96GnPff2nN7bBazgfhEty5IlMlUaLQxBcs04UTSmazIAHc6palv/5N9Ba6pE27JCDlmG/DUkklO0tZAJmX9zFqJMgzawSlmEEmACB1oxEY@nCFSc2U3xPn6YAI7qNKocUAe1JhO57edFBby43VWbwjEYObvxV300h6nTal@XymowWj1YgnD91US0rBvknAj3jHGHG7dH9dMAYlDwfMzgOmU/mmJDnswuXJupINlg58CQME0k4xRXvd0d6c@3V2/44s@8XnfU9T780czrd4PAvmyn@Q4zxRo7BwvSMLju1L7ytN@5MUa4KSRGMML2@fD3EWwyTROS5ppII6S5OF6IVZpL/GCfaRdWvRZl@Qc))

Comment: Yesss exactly what I trying to thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
[A-Z][a-z]*|[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VPZtON/1).

*Details*:

- `[A-Z][a-z]*` - an uppercase letter and then zero or more lowercase letters
- `|` - or
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more letters
- `|` - or
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `|` - or
- `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` - one or more chars other than letters or digits.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/1jgHg2):

```java
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("Hakan2Ev", "Hakan2Ev2", "Ha2Oy2Het3Magara4", "(Ha2Oy2)12");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z][a-z]*|[^a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9]+");
for (String str : strs) {
    System.out.println("--- " + str + " ---");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
--- Hakan2Ev ---
Hakan
2
Ev
--- Hakan2Ev2 ---
Hakan
2
Ev
2
--- Ha2Oy2Het3Magara4 ---
Ha
2
Oy
2
Het
3
Magara
4
--- (Ha2Oy2)12 ---
(
Ha
2
Oy
2
)
12
```